# JSON in Elasticsearch parsing with Newtonsoft

Tags: json, parsing, elasticsearch, json.net

I have a problem parsing JSON string from Elasticsearch using Newtonsoft in the C# language.

The problem is that I sometimes receives a simple array or an array of arrays.

The last part is giving me problems to parse correctly.

The example string shows a type named `'BYGNINGSNUMMER'`. This information have some values, `'vaerdier'`, and in case there are more than one entry I have to find `"'gyldigTil': null"`.

Any idea how to do this?

I have tried almost everything.

```
static string JT_Str = @"
{
'type': 'BYGNINGSNUMMER',
'vaerdier': [
  {
    'sidstOpdateret': '2019-08-12T14:59:48+02:00',
    'vaerdi': '1585',
    'periode': {
      'gyldigFra': '2018-09-30',
      'gyldigTil': '2019-08-11'

    }
},
  {
    'sidstOpdateret': '2019-08-13T17:39:58+02:00',
    'vaerdi': 'B-1585',
    'periode': {
      'gyldigFra': '2019-08-12',
      'gyldigTil': '2019-08-12'
    }
  },
  {
    'sidstOpdateret': '2019-08-13T17:39:58+02:00',
    'vaerdi': 'B1585',
    'periode': {
      'gyldigFra': '2019-08-13',
      'gyldigTil': null
    }
  }
],
'sekvensnr': 0,
'vaerditype': 'string'
},
{
'type': 'PSEUDOCVRNR',
'vaerdier': [
  {
    'sidstOpdateret': '2018-10-26T19:53:28+02:00',
    'vaerdi': 'false',
    'periode': {
      'gyldigFra': '2018-09-30',
      'gyldigTil': null
    }
  }
],
'sekvensnr': 0,
'vaerditype': 'boolean'
},
{
'type': 'VEDTÆGT_SENESTE',
'vaerdier': [
  {
    'sidstOpdateret': '2018-10-26T19:53:28+02:00',
    'vaerdi': '2018-09-30',
    'periode': {
      'gyldigFra': '2018-09-30',
      'gyldigTil': null
    }
  }
],
'sekvensnr': 0,
'vaerditype': 'date'
}
";
```

Comment: What is your problem? Deserialized the json? Please share your c# class. gyldigTil is set as nullable right?

Comment: My problem is that this line (C#):
JObject JO_type = JObject.Parse(JT_Str)

Results in this error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 33, position 6.'

If gyldigTil is null it indicates that there is no ending date set.

Comment: Post your Poco class then. This is a serialisation problem.